# What is the correct way to install bootstrap and babel in webpack

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I am facing difficulty in installing bootstrap in webpack, it say it requires jquery and if i include that, it says it requires popper and when i install popper it says export not supported(I am using ES6).
And also please tell me how to include bootstrap and babel in my project.

Someone please help me out..
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The key is to make sure that the scripts are loaded in proper order. That would mean jquery has to be loaded by the time the bootstrap css is loaded.

For bootstrap with webpack please refer the code [here](https://github.com/rakcheru/webpack-bootstrap/tree/81e6a8b1a5f9e0413786c0bb97ca3effc8fd9f9d).

Adding babel shouldnt be hard. You can see the required changes in this [diff](https://github.com/rakcheru/webpack-bootstrap/commit/11faa5757701422715ff76f1536e3a4a67020f68).